# htaccess not working on some cases

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use htaccess to force www before my domain.

This is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}\/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If i try to go to: http://domain-name.com, it will add correcty the www before the domain, but if i try to go to a directory like domain-name.com/directory it will not force the www before domain.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can drop the \ before the /$1. It's not necessary. We're talking only http: here, and not https:? Otherwise, your code looks fine, and should preserve the entire URI (path/file via $1, and the Query String automatically copied).

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
Yes, it should be fine ... However it's killing me the reason why is not working! :D

Comment: What happens if you hard code your domain name: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-name.com/$1 [R=301,L]` ? Worth trying. Notice that the `\/$1` is now just `/$1`.

Answer (score 0):

try the following - works for me;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately doesn't work.
If i try to go to something like http://domain-name/directory httaccess doesn't add the www before it. It remains the same URL

Comment: I presume you kept the `RewriteEngine on` line from your original question? If so, are there any lines before that in the `.htaccess` file

Comment: Yes, it's there.
If i just go to http://domain-name.com htaccess adds automatically the www, but not with directories

Comment: Not sure I can help then, that code works for me. Unless your config is different, or there's something conflicting with the rules I don't know why it wouldn't work for you.